# How to automatically detect road border in lane detection algorithm?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So the popular approach to lane detection using computer vision is to perform these 5 steps:

1. Convert the image to grayscale, smooth the image by gaussian
   function
2. Use canny edge function to detect edges (obviously right? )
3. Mark the region of interest ROI
4. Use hough transform fucntion to detect straight lines and have line function to draw them.

That's what my approach.
But the point here is we usually need to manually select the ROI. In most case when apply to dash camera on a car, it's ok since the view does not change much.

But my situation is different, I want to detect road lanes based on traffic surveillance cameras, and of course there are many of them. Each camera has its own view, so I think that there must be a way to automatically separate the road and non-road areas.

**My question is how to detect the ROI automatically?**

My idea here is that the road area will have lots of pixel movements and the non-road area will not. From that idea we could automatically detect the ROI.

I have manage to use opencv to extract the background ([background subtracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXK36.png)) from this video (https://youtu.be/bv3NEzjb5sU) using openCV and subtractBackgroundMOG2 function.

The code about canny edge and hough transform is basically ok after we have the ROI. This below is the code to train and extract the background. I though we could modify it to give the region mask or something that can use as ROI for later steps.

Thank you.

```
import cv2
from pathlib import Path



def bg_train(video_source, number_of_run, number_of_frames):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
    fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows=True)
    frame_number = -1
    default_background = Path("default_background.png")

    # the number of loop that will run to create a better background
    i = 0

    # check the file if it's already exist
    if default_background.is_file():
        i = 1
        default_background = "default_background.png"
    else:
        default_background = None
        i = 0

    while i < number_of_run:
        # Capture next frame and show in window
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("frame capture failed or not :)")
            break

        cv2.imshow("training_original", frame)

        # subtract foreground and show in new window
        background_read = cv2.imread(default_background)
        fg = fgbg.apply(frame, background_read, -1)
        fg_mask = filter_mask(fg)
        cv2.imshow('Training_FG', fg_mask)

        # subtract background and show in new window
        bg = fgbg.getBackgroundImage(fg_mask)
        cv2.imshow('Training_background', bg)
        print(i, frame_number, bg.shape[0], bg.shape[1], bg.shape[2])

        # Counting frame and save the final background after training
        frame_number += 1
        if frame_number == number_of_frames and i < number_of_run - 1:
            i += 1
            cv2.imwrite("default_background.png", bg)
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
            frame_number = -1
        elif frame_number == number_of_frames and i == number_of_run - 1:
            i += 1
            cv2.imwrite("background_final.png", bg)
            cv2.imshow("final background", bg)
            return 1, bg

        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            print("exit by user...")
            return 0, None

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def main():
    video_source = "highway-30s.mp4"
    check, background_after = bg_train(video_source, 2, 500)
    if check == 0:
        return 0
    elif check == 1:
        cv2.imshow("the background, press ESC to close window", background_after)
        c = cv2.waitKey(0)
        if c == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could train the algorithm to pick the ROI, over an initial amount of time, by tracking movement in the viewport over a series of frames.

Filter out movements and create lines/vectors representing their direction.  Once you have enough of these samples you can figure out the best ROI by using a bounding box which encapsulates these vectors.